# Abnormal behavior when parsing an array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Since yesterday I am facing with a strange behavior of shell code.

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

operatori="/*-+="


temp=$1
len_temp=${#temp}

for (( i=0; i<$len_temp; i++ ))
  do
    array[i]=${temp:i:1}
    #echo 'i= '${array[i]}
  done

for i in ${array[@]}
  do
    if [[ "$operatori" =~ "$i" ]]; then
      echo '@@'$i
    fi
  done
```

It is executed with `$1 = tom*jerry-1=0`.
In this version of the code , i expect to return:

```
@@*
@@-
@@=
```

But it returns just

```
@@- 
@@=
```

On the  other hand, I tried to deny the condition, having

```
if ! [[ "$operatori" =~ "$i" ]]; then
```

But the result is more strange:

```
@@t
@@o
@@m
@@analyzer.sh
@@gnome-terminal.desktop
@@mount location.sh
@@test.sh
@@j
@@e
@@r
@@r
@@y
@@1
@@0
```

Where I expect to receive:

```
@@t
@@o
@@m
@@j
@@e
@@r
@@r
@@y
@@1
@@0
```

where the analyzer.sh, gnome-teminal.desktop, mount location.sh, test.sh represents some files from the same location where my code  is saved.

Can anyone tell me what am I  doing wrong?

Comment: What's the command you're running? Looks like when you type `tom*jerry` in the shell, `*` is expanded to a list of files in that directory by glob expansion.

Comment: I am launching the script with  `./test.sh tom*jerry-1=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set bash to `noglob` as first command of your script to prevent globbing with `*` :

```
set -o noglob
```

**Update :**

Use `set +o noglob` to set noglob back to off when your script needs wildcard expansion :

```
set -o noglob
for i in ${array[@]}
  do
    if [[ "$operatori" =~ "$i" ]]; then
      echo '@@'$i
    fi
  done
set +o noglob
```

**Note :** @mikcutu, the `noglob` solution is a (working) workaround. See @Gordon Davisson's answer for details about why you first should double-quote your variables to prevent word splitting.

Comment: Downvote: this fixes *some* symptoms but not the actual problem, which is improper quoting. Many scripts also need globbing, so this is a limited workaround at best.

Comment: You're partially right : the real problem is about quoting, but about "scripts that also need globbing" : when set to `on` the noglob  can be turned back to `off` after use. Anyway I tried to delete my answer but I can't as it's accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap variable references in double-quotes to prevent unexpected parsing oddities. In particular, use `for i in "${array[@]}"` and `echo "@@$i"`.

What's happening here is that in the `for` statement, the array expands to the equivalent of `t o m * j e r r y - 1 = 0`, which then undergoes word splitting (ok in this case) and wildcard expansion (which replaces the `*` with a list of files in the current directory), giving the equivalent of `t o m analyzer.sh gnome-terminal.desktop 'mount location.sh' test.sh j e r r y - 1 = 0`, which then causes the weird results you're seeing.

You could avoid this problem by setting the `noglob` shell option (as Kenavoz) suggested), but this will break any parts of the script that depend on wildcard expansion (and still leaves the potential for unexpected word splitting). It's better to just use double-quotes.

Comment: I tried to raise "unexpected word splitting" when using `set -o noglob` but with no success to make the OP script fail.